# Content profile image (CCK imagefield) instead of default drupal picture

Tags: nodes

tried what igorik said on drupal.org == http://drupal.org/node/609454#comment-2172258
Placed user-picture.tpl.php in my theme directory and replaced code inside it:

```
<div class="picture">
<?php print $picture; ?>
</div>
```

to:

```
<?php
$img_url = $content_profile->get_variable('profile', 'field_photo');
print l(theme('imagecache', 'msg_profile_pic', $img_url), 'user/' . $account->uid );
?>
```

but all what im getting after these actions is WSOD... set to display errors true in index.php, but still can't see any errors. Help me guys! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To find out errors in WSOD you can look at you Apache Error Log, in Ubuntu you can execute `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` and you will see the php error.

It's pretty sure the problem come from $content_profile which doesn't seem to be instanciated and thus don't carry the whole content profile object. You can load it using [content_profile_load](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--content_profile--content_profile.module/function/content_profile_load/6).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the [ImageField Avatar](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield_avatar) module which is able to automatically synchronize images from a content_profile CCK ImageField to the core drupal user picture field.

Comment: Thanks, but i won't use a module for this task. I want this programmatic done.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `$content_profile` variable is `NULL` in `user-picture.tpl.php` file, while you don't explicitly load its contents with [content_profile_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--content_profile--content_profile.module/function/content_profile_load/6) function or make this variable available in this template too. (Citing from the official readme about the places where this variable is available: "The $content_profile variable is available in the page, node, comment, user_name, user_profile, user_signature, search_result and some other templates.")

I think it's a better solution to create your own [`user-profile.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile.tpl.php/6) (you should copy it from `/modules/user` directory to your own theme's `templates` directory, and delete theme registry cache after that), where the `$content_profile` variable is already set, and print the customized user profile picture in this one.

When you use the Content Profile module's `get_variable()` function, you usually get an `array` or `NULL` (if the variable doesn't exist).
If it's an image field (and you query its content with e.g. `$content_profile->get_variable('profile', 'field_photo');`), the content of the variable looks something like this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'filename' => 'default_avatar1.gif',
    'filepath' => 'sites/default/files/imagefield_default_images/default_avatar1.gif',
    'filemime' => 'image/gif',
    'source' => 'default_image_upload',
    'destination' => 'sites/default/files/imagefield_default_images/default_avatar1.gif',
    'filesize' => 5711,
    'uid' => '1',
    'status' => 1,
    'timestamp' => 1320633662,
    'fid' => '54',
    'default' => true,
    'nid' => '446',
  ),
)
```

So in your case, you should rather do something like this (in the appropriate place in `user-profile.tpl.php` file):

```
$user_profile_photo = $content_profile->get_variable('profile', 'field_photo');

print l( theme('imagecache', 'msg_profile_pic', $user_profile_photo[0]['filepath'], 'just a test image', 'test image'), 'user/'.$account->uid, array('html' => true) );
```

Of course, `'field_photo'` must be a valid CCK field (previously set in Content Profile's fields), and `'msg_profile_pic'` must be a valid ImageCache preset.
Just tested, it works on my site.